Routes are getting lost on OVH VPS
For my tunnel I have added the following route and rule:
ip rule add from 127.0.0.1/8 iif lo table 123
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 123

It works fine for a few weeks and then it suddenly disappears without reboot although I have persisted it on /etc/network/if-up.d/localroute. Do I have to add it to another place like netplan?

Debian 12
OVH VPS
/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg

network: {config: disabled}


Don't crosspost.

Yes, there was apt upgrade which restarted systemd-networkd.service


Do I have to add it to another place like netplan?

If you have systemd-networkd running, it will clear out all "foreign" configuration from interfaces it manages. In that case you need to add the configuration either to Netplan (which will generate a networkd profile), or directly to networkd itself. See man systemd.network and networkctl.
Networkd does have a global option to keep foreign configuration, see man networkd.conf. But usually it's a better idea to define the configuration you want and let networkd apply it for you.
(Or in general, it's best to avoid mixing multiple network configuration tools – if you're using ifupdown then disable networkd/Netplan, and if you're using networkd/Netplan then don't use ifupdown.)
